# html/javascript: Is there a way to force data inputted into a text input to go into its value attribute?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

What i have is a div with text inputs. What i want to do is send the div's HTML code to the server to be used on another page like so:

```
$.ajax({
        url: 'process.php',
        type: 'POST',
        data: {
            html: $("#form").html()
        },
        success: function (data) {

        }
    });
```

The thing is, if a user types in some data into the text inputs, that data is lost since its not part of the HTML. Is there a way i can force this data into the HTML? eg by using javascript to edit each input's value attribute?

Thanks in advance

Comment: use a change event handler and update the value attribute

Comment: Or while sending the data to the server you can equip the relevant input element's value attribute with its original value.

Comment: you just want to send textbox value to the server side??

Comment: as Arun said, you have to use event handlers. for example, as you're using jquery, you should do something like this : $('body').on('change','#yourTextInput',function(event){ //set value as input contents... + send this.val() in your ajax... });

Comment: @Pratik No i want to send the whole HTML. including any input a user may have entered

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the `input` event:

```
$(document).on('input', 'input.your_input', function() {
    var that = $(this);
    that.attr('value', that.val());
});
```

Inspect the input element and try type something:

```js
$(document).on('input', '#textInp', function() {
  var that = $(this); 
  that.attr('value', that.val());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="textInp" />
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try sending the input values via parameters in the ajax function.

Answer (score 0):

Try to run this snippet before making the call,

```
$("#form :text").attr("value",funcion(){
  return $(this).val();
});
```

Instead of binding change event to all the input elements initially you can add the attribute before sending them to server.

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this:

```
$("input").on('change', function() {
    $(this).attr('value', $(this).val());
});
```